# How can I create a square 2d array of size NxN where N is supplied by the user and populated with random numbers at a certain range?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

My goal is for the user to input a number from the range 3 to 8 and it will a create matrices based on that size and then fill it with random numbers from the range of -12 to 8.

for example if the user enters 3

it should display :

```
9 1 -4
4 2 -6
-11 5 8
```

I think I've got the concept right but the variable length array confuses me cause I know it's not possible to create an array that isn't constant unless you use std:vector but I dont know how to implement that in this code.

I keep getting the error "subscript requires array or pointer type"

```
#include<iostream>
#include <random>
#include<time.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void array_gen(int* array, int arraysize) // void function to generate the array with random numbers 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < arraysize;i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % -12 + 8;    // used to generate numbers from 0 to 10 
    }

}

void arraydis(int* array, int arraysize)     // function to sort array 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < arraysize;i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < arraysize;j++)
        {
        std:cout << array[i][j];
        }
    }

}


int main()
{
    int arraysize = 0, i;
    cout << "Enter array in the range of 50 <= size <= 200: ";    // records the users input 
    cin >> arraysize;

    int* array = new int[arraysize], freq[10];
    array_gen(array, arraysize);


    cout << "unSorted array is:";      // shows the unsorted array 
    arraydis(array, arraysize);
}
```

Comment: `int* array` and `array[i][j]`? You do it correctly in `array_gen`, but then in `arraydis` you treat `array` as a "2D" array (a matrix) which it isn't.

Comment: `rand() % -12 + 8;    // used to generate numbers from 0 to 10`, no, you probably want `rand() % 20 - 12;// [-12;8[`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude where would I implement that?

Comment: So why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` can be highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is *barely* random at all.

Comment: If you want a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) you need to use pointers to pointers. As in `int** array = new int*[arraysize];` then allocate each sub-array separately in a loop (as e.g. `array[i] = new int[arraysize]`). Or use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(arraysize, std::vector<int>(arraysize));`

Comment: On the other hand, of you *don't* want a "2D" array, then don't have the inner loop (the loop over `j`) and don't use double array-indexing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I actually want a 2D array with like if the input was 2 the output should be  4 5 /n 8 7 /n

Comment: So your actual question is: "How can I create a square 2d array of size NxN where N is supplied by the user?"

Comment: As an aside I needed a few seconds to correctly parse `int* array = new int[arraysize], freq[10];`. Do not combine declarations of complex variables in a single line. The comma has more than one meaning in C/C++.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  yes that is literally want I want to do except it is populated with random numbers at a certain range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use a vector of vector of ints, using `std::vector`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <random>
#include<time.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

// generate the array with random numbers 
    
void array_gen(vector<vector<int>> & array, size_t arraysize)
{
  array.resize(arraysize);
  for (auto& line : array)
    line.resize(arraysize);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < arraysize; j++)
    {
      array[i][j] = rand() % -12 + 8;    // generate numbers from 0 to 10 
    }
  }
}

void arraydis(const vector<vector<int>> & array)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < array.size(); j++)
    {
      cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
}    

int main()
{
  int arraysize = 0, i;
  cout << "Enter array in the range of 50 <= size <= 200: ";    // records the users input 
  cin >> arraysize;

  vector<vector<int>> array;
  array_gen(array, arraysize);

  cout << "unSorted array is:\n";      // shows the unsorted array 
  arraydis(array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much !!! That's is exactly what i was looking for. I think I understand what the std::vector does now. Thanks again